# SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.example.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, firefox, https, django-cms

Recently, I set up Nginx caching for a server. I went about doing this by including the [following files](https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx) in my Nginx config.

As a result, the site loads much faster. However, I cannot seem to bring up the admin part of the CMS. It tries to open the window (iframe?), but then promptly closes it with the following error displayed:

In Chrome:

> SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.example.com"
> from accessing a cross-origin frame.

In Firefox:

> SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "document" on
> cross-origin object

In my `nginx.conf` the following settings seem pertinent:

```
  # Add Referrer-Policy for HTML documents.
  # h5bp/security/referrer-policy.conf
  map $sent_http_content_type $referrer_policy {
    ~*text/(css|html|javascript)|application\/pdf|xml "strict-origin-when-cross-origin";
  }

  # Add Cross-Origin-Policies for HTML documents.
  # h5bp/security/cross-origin-policy.conf
  # Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy
  map $sent_http_content_type $coep_policy {
    ~*text/(html|javascript)|application/pdf|xml "require-corp";
  }
  # Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy
  map $sent_http_content_type $coop_policy {
    ~*text/(html|javascript)|application/pdf|xml "same-origin";
  }
  # Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy
  map $sent_http_content_type $corp_policy {
    ~*text/(html|javascript)|application/pdf|xml "same-origin";
  }
```

In the site's Nginx configuration, I have the following mention to include the Nginx configs mentioned above. If I comment out this entry, everything works again

```
 #includes templates for basic Nginx behavior, such as caching
 include h5bp/basic.conf;
```

It appears that I need to tweak some settings as they appear too strict. Am I correct? What should the settings be? If it helps, I use [DjangoCMS](https://github.com/django-cms/django-cms) version 3.7.4

Comment: Have you got `X_FRAME_OPTIONS` defined in your settings?