# Why not give an error when I change a variable name?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a calculator, but the JavaScript file shows an error.

```js
var top = document.getElementById('top');
var bottom = document.getElementById('bottom');



function calculator(value) {
    if (value === 'AC') {
        top.innerText = (top.innerText).slice(0, -1);
    } else if (value === '=') {
        top.innerText = ''
    } else {
        top.innerText += value;
    }
    bottom.innerText = `${eval(((top.innerText)).replace('%', '/100').replace('x', '*'))}`;
    if (bottom.innerText === 'undefined') {
        bottom.innerText = 0;
    }

}
```

```css
button {
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: 200%;
    width: 6%;
    background: #F7ECDE;
    border: 2px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0 2px #999;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:active {
    box-shadow: 0 3px #666;
    transform: translateY(2px);
}

button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.709);
    color: rgb(215, 254, 255);
    transition: background-color .5s;
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
}

.display {
    height: 75px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 24.6%;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.top,
.bottom {
    background: rgb(219, 204, 204);
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-align: right;
}

.top {
    font-size: 100%;
    height: 25px;
}

.bottom {
    font-size: 200%;
    height: 50px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

@media (max-width:950px) {
    button {
        font-size: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="display">
            <div id="top" class="top"></div>
            <div id="bottom" class="bottom"></div>
        </div>
        <div><button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">(</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">)</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">%</button>
            <button ondblclick="Top.innerText=''" class="AC" onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">AC</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">7</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">8</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">9</button>
            <button on onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">/</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">4</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">5</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">6</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">x</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">1</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">2</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">3</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">-</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)" class="zero">0</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">.</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">=</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">+</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

The error shows when I use this code. But if I change change variable name `top` to anything else in the JavaScript file it works perfectly.

```js
var Top = document.getElementById('top');
var bottom = document.getElementById('bottom');



function calculator(value) {
    if (value === 'AC') {
        Top.innerText = (Top.innerText).slice(0, -1);
    } else if (value === '=') {
        Top.innerText = ''
    } else {
        Top.innerText += value;
    }
    bottom.innerText = `${eval(((Top.innerText)).replace('%', '/100').replace('x', '*'))}`;
    if (bottom.innerText === 'undefined') {
        bottom.innerText = 0;
    }

}
```

```css
button {
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-size: 200%;
    width: 6%;
    background: #F7ECDE;
    border: 2px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0 2px #999;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:active {
    box-shadow: 0 3px #666;
    transform: translateY(2px);
}

button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.709);
    color: rgb(215, 254, 255);
    transition: background-color .5s;
}

.container {
    text-align: center;
}

.display {
    height: 75px;
    margin: auto;
    width: 24.6%;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.top,
.bottom {
    background: rgb(219, 204, 204);
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-align: right;
}

.top {
    font-size: 100%;
    height: 25px;
}

.bottom {
    font-size: 200%;
    height: 50px;
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}

@media (max-width:950px) {
    button {
        font-size: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
    <script defer src="/js/index.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="display">
            <div id="top" class="top"></div>
            <div id="bottom" class="bottom"></div>
        </div>
        <div><button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">(</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">)</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">%</button>
            <button ondblclick="Top.innerText=''" class="AC" onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">AC</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">7</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">8</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">9</button>
            <button on onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">/</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">4</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">5</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">6</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">x</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">1</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">2</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">3</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">-</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)" class="zero">0</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">.</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">=</button>
            <button onclick="calculator(this.innerText)">+</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: similar to [this qs asked 22hrs ago!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70989105/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-https-www-example-com-from-access)

Answer (score 1):

This shows an error, because *top* returns the topmost window in the hierarchy of window objects. If you do `console.log(top)`, you will find a `window object` instead of HtmlElement.